# Php wont load because query return no rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am having php file with code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Proizvod.PROIZVODID, Proizvod.NAZIV, Proizvod.SLIKA
FROM PROIZVOD_GRUPE
LEFT JOIN Proizvod ON PROIZVOD_GRUPE.PROIZVODID = Proizvod.PROIZVODID WHERE PROIZVOD_GRUPE.PROIZVOD_GRUPAID = 1 AND AKTIVAN = 1;";
```

Problem is second line where if it return 0 rows it crash php file. When i remove second line my php loads normally.

my full code of that file is:

```
<?php
    require('../Php/ConfigBaza.php');
$sql = "SELECT Proizvod.PROIZVODID, Proizvod.NAZIV, Proizvod.SLIKA
FROM PROIZVOD_GRUPE
LEFT JOIN Proizvod ON PROIZVOD_GRUPE.PROIZVODID = Proizvod.PROIZVODID WHERE PROIZVOD_GRUPE.PROIZVOD_GRUPAID = 1 AND AKTIVAN = 1;";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows < 1)
    {
        echo("Doslo je do greske prilikom ucitavanja proizvoda!");
        die();
    }
    else
    {

        echo("
        <div id='overlay' style='display: none; position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999; background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.39);'>
            <div id='kolicina_overlay' style='display: none; position: fixed; width: 500px; height: 110px; margin-top: -55px; margin-left: -150px; top: 50%; left: 50%; text-align: center; background-color: #2196F3; z-index: 1000'>
                <p style='font-weight: bolder'>Unesite zeljenu kolicinu!</p>
                <input type='number' value='1' style='width: 50px'>
                <div id='kolicina_potvrdi_button' style='padding: 10px; color: white;' onclick='UnesiKolicinu()'>Potvrdi</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ");
        while($proizvod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $pid = $proizvod['PROIZVODID'];
            $naziv = $proizvod['NAZIV'];
            $slika = $proizvod['SLIKA'];
            $rabat = $proizvod['POPUST'];

            if(!isset($slika) || empty($slika))
            {
                $slika = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/600px-No_image_available.svg.png";
            }
            echo("
                <div class='proizvod_Box' id='$pid' onclick='IdiNaProizvod(id)'>
                    <div class='proizvod_Naslov'>
                        <p>$naziv</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='proizvod_Slika'>
                        <img src='$slika'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ");
        }
    }
?>
```

So why is it happening and how to prevent it?

What i came across is that when let's say my `PROIZVODID = 1` and inside table `PROIZVOD_GRUPE` i do not have records of it but inside `Proizvod` i do and it doesn't meet `AKTIVAN = 1` then it will show BUT if i do have row with `PROIZVODID = 1` inside `PROIZVOD_GRUPE` and still doesn't meet `AKTIVAN = 1` from `Proizvod` it crashes

Comment: Please include the error message of the crash.

Comment: check if the query is valid ..

Comment: @TobiasK there is no error message (or i do not know where to find it), just my page on website wont load

Comment: @scaisEdge it is valid since if i change parameters in my database to meet condition and there is atleast one row which meets it it loads normally

Comment: enable error reporting by http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.

Comment: Look at edited question i misscopied SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

First your script is vulnerable to XSS Attack. I do not see where you are escaping the outputted variables with htmlentities or htmlspecialchars() functions. Please always use **error_reporting(0);** in production to hide your php error notices on the screen

Your problem seems to be mysqli_connection parameter in the line of code you specified.

based on my connection i change this

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

For testing create table as follows and insert into it

```
create table Proizvod(id int primary key auto_increment, PROIZVODID varchar(100), NAZIV varchar(100), SLIKA varchar(100)
 ,AKCIJSKI_ARTIKAL varchar(100), AKTIVAN varchar(100),
POPUST varchar(100));

insert into Proizvod(PROIZVODID,NAZIV,SLIKA,AKCIJSKI_ARTIKAL,AKTIVAN,POPUST)values
('pp','naz','sik','1','1','image.png');




<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $dbname = 'angular';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';


    $sql = "SELECT PROIZVODID, NAZIV, SLIKA FROM Proizvod WHERE AKCIJSKI_ARTIKAL = 1 AND AKTIVAN = 1;";

    //$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result->num_rows < 1)
    {
        echo("Doslo je do greske prilikom ucitavanja proizvoda!");
        die();
    }
    else
    {

        echo("
        <div id='overlay' style='display: none; position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999; background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.39);'>
            <div id='kolicina_overlay' style='display: none; position: fixed; width: 500px; height: 110px; margin-top: -55px; margin-left: -150px; top: 50%; left: 50%; text-align: center; background-color: #2196F3; z-index: 1000'>
                <p style='font-weight: bolder'>Unesite zeljenu kolicinu!</p>
                <input type='number' value='1' style='width: 50px'>
                <div id='kolicina_potvrdi_button' style='padding: 10px; color: white;' onclick='UnesiKolicinu()'>Potvrdi</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ");
        while($proizvod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $pid =htmlentities($proizvod['PROIZVODID'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $naziv = htmlentities($proizvod['NAZIV'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $slika = htmlentities($proizvod['SLIKA'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            //$rabat = htmlentities($proizvod['POPUST'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");



            if(!isset($slika) || empty($slika))
            {
                $slika = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/600px-No_image_available.svg.png";
            }
            echo("
                <div class='proizvod_Box' id='$pid' onclick='IdiNaProizvod(id)'>
                    <div class='proizvod_Naslov'>
                        <p>$naziv</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='proizvod_Slika'>
                        <img src='$slika'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ");
        }
    }
?>
```